# Magento 2 TypeError: options is undefined in firefox

Tags: magento2, cache, customer-session, browser, customer-data

After working for few day I noticed that I am getting this issue in my Firefox and not in Chrome.

> TypeError: options is undefined

If I do cache clean and check in Firefox it works for the first time, for the next refresh face this issue

Some one help me with this.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you ever find the fix to this issue?

Comment: No I did a fresh installation with my Theme(Perl) of Magento 2.2.0 facing issue I cant see the welcome message drop-down of user in header. With fresh installation of extension BSS_GDPR getting this error again, Not Sure this is a Core issue of Magento Version. Updated images.

Comment: Yeah i have a customer with this issue, thought it was the way my javascript was being loaded, but after changing some require config js files its still happening.

Comment: I have tried reaching the extension team lets check, Also I am trying to debug the issue, Will get back sure.